# iMac wakes up without any noticeable reason

Tags: macos, imac, sleep-wake

I have a iMac 27" late 2012, OS X 10.8.4 and last night it woke up from sleep-mode while I was 3 meters away from it. Nobody but me was in the room. The login-Screen was visible. After some seconds the main screen went black again, but the screen of the second monitor (from LG, connected via a thunderbolt-adapter) kept glowing in a dark gray light. So I hit a key on the keyboard, the mac woke up again, and I sent it to sleep by pressing the power-button. Now both screen was black and I went to bed.

I did google that today and I found the command `pmset -g log` which prints out a hybernate-log, and in this log I found evidence for even more strange wake-up-events. This is a part of this log:

```
Time stamp                Domain                Message                                                                     Duration    Delay     
==========                ======                =======                                                                     ========    =====     
UUID: EBB08E57-0FC8-4724-AD4B-30629C0130BE
2013-08-10 18:49:57 MESZ Sleep                  Power Button Sleep Sleep: Using AC                                          4204 secs 
2013-08-10 18:49:57 MESZ Assertions             PID 182(apsd) Released ApplePushServiceTask "com.apple.apsd-waitingformessages-push.apple.com" 00:16:58  id:0xc00000d3d Aggregate:0x1040    
2013-08-10 18:49:57 MESZ WakeRequests           Clients requested wake events: None                                         
2013-08-10 20:00:01 MESZ DarkWake               DarkWake due to EC.SleepTimer/SleepTimer: Using AC                          0 secs    
2013-08-10 20:00:01 MESZ HibernateStats         hibmode=0 standbydelay=4200                                                             rd=662 ms   
2013-08-10 20:00:01 MESZ Sleep                  Maintenance Sleep Sleep: Using AC                                           10250 secs
2013-08-10 20:00:04 MESZ Assertions             PID 13(UserEventAgent) Created BackgroundTask "Checking for Software Updates (com.apple.SoftwareUpdate.DarkWakeFire)" 00:00:04  id:0xc00000d86 Aggregate:0x1040 
2013-08-10 20:00:04 MESZ Assertions             PID 1979(SoftwareUpdateC) Created BackgroundTask "Checking for Software Updates (com.apple.SoftwareUpdate.BackgroundDownload)" 00:00:04  id:0xc00000d88 Aggregate:0x1040    
2013-08-10 20:00:06 MESZ Assertions             PID 1979(SoftwareUpdateC) Released BackgroundTask "Checking for Software Updates (com.apple.SoftwareUpdate.BackgroundDownload)" 00:00:06  id:0xc00000d88 Aggregate:0x1040   
2013-08-10 20:00:06 MESZ Assertions             PID 13(UserEventAgent) Released BackgroundTask "Checking for Software Updates (com.apple.SoftwareUpdate.DarkWakeFire)" 00:00:06  id:0xc00000d86 Aggregate:0x1040    
2013-08-10 20:00:17 MESZ SlowResponse           PMConnection: Response from mDNSResponder is slow (powercaps:0x0)                       15994 ms    
2013-08-10 20:00:17 MESZ WakeRequests           Clients requested wake events: None                                         
2013-08-10 22:50:51 MESZ Wake                   Wake from Standby due to EC.SleepTimer/SleepTimer: Using AC                 39 secs   
2013-08-10 22:50:51 MESZ HibernateStats         hibmode=0 standbydelay=4200                                                             rd=654 ms   
2013-08-10 22:50:59 MESZ Assertions             PID 182(apsd) Created ApplePushServiceTask "com.apple.apsd-waitingformessages-push.apple.com" 00:00:05  id:0xc00000dca Aggregate:0x1040 
2013-08-10 22:51:13 MESZ Assertions             PID 182(apsd) TimedOut ApplePushServiceTask "com.apple.apsd-waitingformessages-push.apple.com" 00:00:19  id:0xc00000dca Aggregate:0x1040    
2013-08-10 22:51:13 MESZ Assertions             Summary- Aggregate:0x40 Using AC                                            
Sleep/Wakes since boot:27   Dark Wake Count in this sleep cycle:1

Time stamp                Domain                Message                                                                     Duration    Delay     
==========                ======                =======                                                                     ========    =====     
UUID: 5CD9A4D4-6924-4423-A3FF-D2DCC23BAD4F
2013-08-10 22:51:30 MESZ Sleep                  Power Button Sleep Sleep: Using AC                                          4205 secs 
2013-08-10 22:51:30 MESZ SlowResponse           Kernel: Response from powerd is slow                                                    15997 ms    
2013-08-10 22:51:30 MESZ Assertions             PID 182(apsd) Released ApplePushServiceTask "com.apple.apsd-waitingformessages-push.apple.com" 00:00:37  id:0xc00000dca Aggregate:0x1040    
2013-08-10 22:51:30 MESZ WakeRequests           Clients requested wake events: None                                         
2013-08-11 00:01:35 MESZ DarkWake               DarkWake due to EC.SleepTimer/SleepTimer: Using AC                          0 secs    
2013-08-11 00:01:35 MESZ HibernateStats         hibmode=0 standbydelay=4200                                                             rd=654 ms   
2013-08-11 00:01:35 MESZ Sleep                  Maintenance Sleep Sleep: Using AC                                           10240 secs
2013-08-11 00:01:40 MESZ Assertions             PID 144(UserEventAgent) Created BackgroundTask "Checking for Software Updates (com.apple.SoftwareUpdate.DarkWakeFire)" 00:00:04  id:0xc00000de6 Aggregate:0x1040    
2013-08-11 00:01:44 MESZ Assertions             PID 144(UserEventAgent) Released BackgroundTask "Checking for Software Updates (com.apple.SoftwareUpdate.DarkWakeFire)" 00:00:09  id:0xc00000de6 Aggregate:0x40 
2013-08-11 00:01:51 MESZ SlowResponse           PMConnection: Response from mDNSResponder is slow (powercaps:0x0)                       16002 ms    
2013-08-11 00:01:51 MESZ WakeRequests           Clients requested wake events: None                                         
2013-08-11 02:52:04 MESZ Assertions             PID 2005(helpd) Created BackgroundTask "com.apple.helpd.sdmbuilding" 00:00:07  id:0xc00000df9 Aggregate:0x1040  
2013-08-11 02:52:15 MESZ Wake                   Wake from Standby due to EC.SleepTimer/SleepTimer: Using AC                 313 secs  
2013-08-11 02:52:15 MESZ HibernateStats         hibmode=0 standbydelay=4200                                                             rd=717 ms   
2013-08-11 02:52:25 MESZ Assertions             PID 182(apsd) Created ApplePushServiceTask "com.apple.apsd-waitingformessages-push.apple.com" 00:00:08  id:0xc00000e23 Aggregate:0x1040 
2013-08-11 02:52:37 MESZ Assertions             PID 182(apsd) TimedOut ApplePushServiceTask "com.apple.apsd-waitingformessages-push.apple.com" 00:00:20  id:0xc00000e23 Aggregate:0x1040    
2013-08-11 02:52:37 MESZ Assertions             Summary- Aggregate:0x1040 Using AC                                          
2013-08-11 02:53:17 MESZ Assertions             PID 2016(SubmitDiagInfo) Created PreventSystemSleep "com.apple.SubmitDiagInfo.run" 00:00:00  id:0x800000e35 Aggregate:0x11140   
2013-08-11 02:53:18 MESZ Assertions             PID 2016(SubmitDiagInfo) Released PreventSystemSleep "com.apple.SubmitDiagInfo.run" 00:00:00  id:0x800000e35 Aggregate:0x1040   
2013-08-11 02:57:28 MESZ Assertions             PID 2005(helpd) Released BackgroundTask "com.apple.helpd.sdmbuilding" 00:05:32  id:0xc00000df9 Aggregate:0x40   
Sleep/Wakes since boot:29   Dark Wake Count in this sleep cycle:1

Time stamp                Domain                Message                                                                     Duration    Delay     
==========                ======                =======                                                                     ========    =====     
UUID: B5690C9E-7E6A-4FC8-9C71-D561FC8CD702
2013-08-11 02:57:28 MESZ Sleep                  Idle Sleep Sleep: Using AC                                                  4204 secs 
2013-08-11 02:57:28 MESZ SlowResponse           Kernel: Response from powerd is slow                                                    15998 ms    
2013-08-11 02:57:28 MESZ Assertions             PID 182(apsd) Released ApplePushServiceTask "com.apple.apsd-waitingformessages-push.apple.com" 00:05:11  id:0xc00000e23 Aggregate:0x1040    
2013-08-11 02:57:28 MESZ WakeRequests           Clients requested wake events: None                                         
2013-08-11 04:07:32 MESZ DarkWake               DarkWake due to EC.SleepTimer/SleepTimer: Using AC                          0 secs    
2013-08-11 04:07:32 MESZ HibernateStats         hibmode=0 standbydelay=4200                                                             rd=717 ms   
2013-08-11 04:07:32 MESZ Sleep                  Maintenance Sleep Sleep: Using AC                                           5314 secs 
2013-08-11 04:07:38 MESZ Assertions             PID 144(UserEventAgent) Created BackgroundTask "Checking for Software Updates (com.apple.SoftwareUpdate.DarkWakeFire)" 00:00:05  id:0xc00000e4a Aggregate:0x1040    
2013-08-11 04:07:42 MESZ Assertions             PID 144(UserEventAgent) Released BackgroundTask "Checking for Software Updates (com.apple.SoftwareUpdate.DarkWakeFire)" 00:00:09  id:0xc00000e4a Aggregate:0x40 
2013-08-11 04:07:48 MESZ SlowResponse           PMConnection: Response from mDNSResponder is slow (powercaps:0x0)                       15995 ms    
2013-08-11 04:07:48 MESZ WakeRequests           Clients requested wake events: None                                         
2013-08-11 05:36:06 MESZ Wake                   Wake from Standby due to EHC1/: Using AC                                    1786 secs 
2013-08-11 05:36:06 MESZ HibernateStats         hibmode=0 standbydelay=4200                                                             rd=807 ms   
2013-08-11 05:36:14 MESZ Assertions             PID 182(apsd) Created ApplePushServiceTask "com.apple.apsd-waitingformessages-push.apple.com" 00:00:06  id:0xc00000e6e Aggregate:0x1040 
2013-08-11 05:36:28 MESZ Assertions             PID 182(apsd) TimedOut ApplePushServiceTask "com.apple.apsd-waitingformessages-push.apple.com" 00:00:20  id:0xc00000e6e Aggregate:0x1040    
2013-08-11 05:36:28 MESZ Assertions             Summary- Aggregate:0x40 Using AC                                            
2013-08-11 05:36:53 MESZ Assertions             PID 124(coreaudiod) Created NoIdleSleepAssertion "com.apple.audio.'AppleHDAEngineOutput:1B,0,1,2:0'.noidlesleep" 00:00:08  id:0x100000e7d Aggregate:0x42    
2013-08-11 05:37:31 MESZ Assertions             PID 124(coreaudiod) Released NoIdleSleepAssertion "com.apple.audio.'AppleHDAEngineOutput:1B,0,1,2:0'.noidlesleep" 00:00:45  id:0x100000e7d Aggregate:0x40   
2013-08-11 05:38:01 MESZ Assertions             PID 124(coreaudiod) Created NoIdleSleepAssertion "com.apple.audio.'AppleHDAEngineOutput:1B,0,1,2:0'.noidlesleep" 00:00:07  id:0x100000e82 Aggregate:0x42    
2013-08-11 05:40:44 MESZ Assertions             PID 124(coreaudiod) Released NoIdleSleepAssertion "com.apple.audio.'AppleHDAEngineOutput:1B,0,1,2:0'.noidlesleep" 00:02:50  id:0x100000e82 Aggregate:0x40   
2013-08-11 05:42:05 MESZ Assertions             PID 124(coreaudiod) Created NoIdleSleepAssertion "com.apple.audio.'AppleHDAEngineOutput:1B,0,1,2:0'.noidlesleep" 00:00:07  id:0x100000e8a Aggregate:0x42    
2013-08-11 05:47:15 MESZ Assertions             PID 124(coreaudiod) Released NoIdleSleepAssertion "com.apple.audio.'AppleHDAEngineOutput:1B,0,1,2:0'.noidlesleep" 00:05:17  id:0x100000e8a Aggregate:0x40   
2013-08-11 05:57:31 MESZ Assertions             PID 124(coreaudiod) Created NoIdleSleepAssertion "com.apple.audio.'AppleHDAEngineOutput:1B,0,1,2:0'.noidlesleep" 00:00:07  id:0x100000e9b Aggregate:0x42    
2013-08-11 05:58:25 MESZ Assertions             PID 124(coreaudiod) Released NoIdleSleepAssertion "com.apple.audio.'AppleHDAEngineOutput:1B,0,1,2:0'.noidlesleep" 00:01:01  id:0x100000e9b Aggregate:0x40   
2013-08-11 05:58:57 MESZ Assertions             PID 124(coreaudiod) Created NoIdleSleepAssertion "com.apple.audio.'AppleHDAEngineOutput:1B,0,1,2:0'.noidlesleep" 00:00:07  id:0x100000e9d Aggregate:0x42    
2013-08-11 05:59:18 MESZ Assertions             PID 124(coreaudiod) Released NoIdleSleepAssertion "com.apple.audio.'AppleHDAEngineOutput:1B,0,1,2:0'.noidlesleep" 00:00:28  id:0x100000e9d Aggregate:0x40   
2013-08-11 06:00:08 MESZ Assertions             PID 124(coreaudiod) Created NoIdleSleepAssertion "com.apple.audio.'AppleHDAEngineOutput:1B,0,1,2:0'.noidlesleep" 00:00:07  id:0x100000e9e Aggregate:0x42    
2013-08-11 06:05:41 MESZ Assertions             PID 124(coreaudiod) Released NoIdleSleepAssertion "com.apple.audio.'AppleHDAEngineOutput:1B,0,1,2:0'.noidlesleep" 00:05:40  id:0x100000e9e Aggregate:0x40   
Sleep/Wakes since boot:31   Dark Wake Count in this sleep cycle:1
```

The spooky wake-up-event I was watching was at 2013-08-10 22:50:51
But the logfile shows even more activities while I was sleeping in my bed:

2013-08-11 00:01:35
2013-08-11 02:52:04
2013-08-11 04:07:32

The next wake-up was initiated by me: 2013-08-11 04:07:32
But what are the reasons for those events in the middle of the night? Why did my iMac wake up?

### UPDATE

```
syslog |grep -i "Wake reason"

Aug 10 20:00:00 huberts-imac kernel[0] <Debug>: Wake reason: EC.SleepTimer (SleepTimer)
Aug 10 22:50:31 huberts-imac kernel[0] <Debug>: Wake reason: EC.SleepTimer (SleepTimer)
Aug 11 00:01:34 huberts-imac kernel[0] <Debug>: Wake reason: EC.SleepTimer (SleepTimer)
Aug 11 02:51:55 huberts-imac kernel[0] <Debug>: Wake reason: EC.SleepTimer (SleepTimer)
Aug 11 04:07:31 huberts-imac kernel[0] <Debug>: Wake reason: EC.SleepTimer (SleepTimer)
Aug 11 05:35:46 huberts-imac kernel[0] <Debug>: Wake reason: EHC1
Aug 11 07:15:55 huberts-imac kernel[0] <Debug>: Wake reason: EC.SleepTimer (SleepTimer)
Aug 11 09:15:54 huberts-imac kernel[0] <Debug>: Wake reason: EHC1
Aug 11 11:14:09 huberts-imac kernel[0] <Debug>: Wake reason: EC.SleepTimer (SleepTimer)
Aug 11 12:40:27 huberts-imac kernel[0] <Debug>: Wake reason: EHC1
Aug 11 13:11:04 huberts-imac kernel[0] <Debug>: Wake reason: EHC1
Aug 11 15:08:25 huberts-imac kernel[0] <Debug>: Wake reason: EC.SleepTimer (SleepTimer)
Aug 11 17:23:56 huberts-imac kernel[0] <Debug>: Wake reason: EHC1
```

`EHC1` corresponds with the times when I did wake up the machine.
`EC.SleepTimer` are wake-ups that happened without my interaction.
What are `EHC1` and `EC.SleepTimer`?

Answer (score 3):

Check your log messages by typing following in Terminal while looking for the time stamp for when it occurred.

```
syslog |grep -i "Wake reason"
```

which will give you a comprehensive report only for wake up reasons.

UPDATE:

Looking at your log now, it all looks normal.

Be aware that the only time your computer can do some housekeeping is during the sleep time. That is intended by design.

However, to prevent **unwanted** wake ups disable the wake for wifi network access.

Comment: I added the output of your command to my posting